# Setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for an MVC site hosted on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, environment-variables, google-cloud-storage

Title says it all pretty much.

I tried uploading the json file to azure storage and referenced it's url when setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable under app settings, but when remotely debugging the site, apparently the url/directory was not in an acceptable format. I can’t store the json file locally either because the website doesn’t have any idea about my C drive directories.

Where should I store this file so that I can set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable for my azure site to the directory of the json file?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is wondering how to handle the Google's credentials smoothly in .Net applications instead of strange way of using the file on server, this is how I solved it for Translation Service. Other services must follow same principle:

- store the content of the Google credentials json file as an environment variable in settings.json/azure configuration for your app (using ' ' instead of " " for inner text):

  ```
  "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "{'type': 'service_account','project_id': ...}"
  ```
- create and return the client:

  ```
    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));
    var channelCredentials = credential.ToChannelCredentials();
    var channel = new Channel(TranslationServiceClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), channelCredentials);
    return TranslationServiceClient.Create(channel);
  ```

Took a while for me to figure it our. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

The `ToChannelCredentials()` approach does not seem to work anymore, so I come up with an other solution that works on Azure. I create a text file in the `/bin` folder of my Azure server with the credentials and then I point the environment variable to this file. Google Cloud API will use this for the default credentials.

```cs
string json = @"{
    'type': 'service_account',
    'project_id': 'xxx',
    'private_key_id': 'xx',
    'private_key': 'xxx',
     ...
}";  // this is the content of the json-credentials file from Google

// Create text file in projects bin-folder 
var binDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase);
string fullPath = Path.Combine(binDirectory, "credentials.json").Replace("file:\\","");

using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(fullPath, false)) {
    outputFile.WriteLine(json);
}

// Set environment variabel to the full file path
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", fullPath);

// Now you can call the service and it will pick up your credentials
TranslationServiceClient client = TranslationServiceClient.Create();
```

Comment: This works for me when running locally. I have a suspicion it will also work on Azure, EXCEPT that I get an error: Access to the path 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.NETCore.App\\3.1.27\\credentials.json' is denied.

Comment: On a Windows based plan - the writable directory is: D:\home\ I'll try to write to D:\home\credentials.json

Comment: I now got an "internal server error" response.

Answer (score 2):

I use the .json file in my local environment (because of environment variable length limit in Windows) and on Azure I use an "Application setting" to set an environment variable. This code handles both cases:

```
string? json;
var filename = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
if (filename != null)
{
    json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
}
else
{
    json = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_STRING");
    if (json == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(
            "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_STRING environment variable with JSON is not set");
    }
}

var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(json).ToChannelCredentials();
var grpcChannel = new Channel("firestore.googleapis.com", credential);
var grcpClient = new Firestore.FirestoreClient(grpcChannel);
var firestoreClient = new FirestoreClientImpl(grcpClient, FirestoreSettings.GetDefault());
return await FirestoreDb.CreateAsync(FirebaseProjectId, firestoreClient);
```

Comment: The code above uses the Google.Cloud.Firestore and FirebaseAdmin nugets

Comment: This is the best answer. The usings are: using Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Grpc.Core;
using Grpc.Auth;

Comment: Locally, you can also use Properties\launchSettings.json to set the environment variable. It worked for me, it was not too long.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking how to set the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" in Azure App Service. The answers here didn't help me. My solution is very simple without any code change.

- In the configuration of the app service go to the Path Mappings
- Add a New Azure Storage Mount. eg /mounts/config
- Add the credentials.json file to the file share
- In the application settings, add the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and set the value to: /mounts/config/credentials.json

That is all.

Comment: It doesn't feel right to put the credentials file in a Storage Mount , I'd like to get it from keyVault

Answer (score 0):

You can store the individual fields from the Application Credential file in Application Settings, and then build a **JsonCredentialParameters** from those values:

```
var projectId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_PROJECT_ID");
var privateKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY");
var parameters = new JsonCredentialParameters
{
    Type = "service_account",
    ProjectId = projectId,
    PrivateKeyId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_PRIVATE_KEY_ID"),
    PrivateKey = privateKey.Replace("\\n", "\n"),
    ClientEmail = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CLIENT_EMAIL"),
    ClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID"),
    TokenUrl = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
};

var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJsonParameters(parameters);
var builder = new FirestoreClientBuilder
{
    Credential = credential
};
var client = await builder.BuildAsync();
var db = await FirestoreDb.CreateAsync(projectId, client);
```

Answer (score -2):

In the **azure app** on the **azure portal** go to **application settings** and add the credentials under **application settings** tab

Then you can reference them in your code as they were in your web.config file.